# Download pdf in memory python

Tags: python, pdf, memory, save

I want to open a pdf in my Python program. So far that works.

```
existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(file(path_to_pdf, "rb"))
```

Right now I open the pdf from my local disk, but I want it to fetch the pdf from the internet, instead of opening it from my local drive. Note that I don't wish to save the existing_pdf, once I fetched it from the internet I will manipulate it and then save it.

I think I need BytesIO + urllib2, but I cannot figure it out, can somebody help me?

So lets say I want to create the variable: existing_pdf with content http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/logpap/example.pdf in it, but I don't wish to download that file first to the disk and then open it. I want to download it 'in memory' and create the variable existing_pdf, which I can later modify in my program.

EDIT:

```
  response=urllib2.urlopen("URL")
  pdf_file = BytesIO(response.read())

  existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
```

It simply hangs and never finishes PdfFileReader(pdf_file)

```
  ....
  existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyPdf\pdf.py", line 374, in __init__
  self.read(stream)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyPdf\pdf.py", line 705, in read
  line = self.readNextEndLine(stream)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyPdf\pdf.py", line 870, in readNextEndLine
  line = x + line
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you try the [requests package](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)?

```
import requests
from StringIO import StringIO
r = requests.get(URL)
pdf_file = StringIO(r.content)
existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
```

This worked for me:

```
import os
import urllib2
from io import BytesIO
URL = "http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/logpap/example.pdf"
response=urllib2.urlopen(URL)
p = BytesIO(response.read())
p.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
print p.tell()
# 79577
```

Comment: Yeah, just tried that and that worked!!! But I don't know why the urllib2 doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like it should have. I find requests to be less finicky.

Comment: for the second example, in Python3 you want to import `urllib` not `urllib2` (deprecated) and the call would be  `response=urllib.request.urlopen(URL)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from urllib.request import urlopen
from io import BytesIO
URL = "http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/logpap/example.pdf"
response=urlopen(URL)
p = BytesIO(response.read())
p.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
print(p.tell())
```

urllib2 didnt work in 2021. Use the example above.